# Permissions Issue with WordPress

Tags: permissions

I've been working on securing my WordPress site. It was all working before I changed the permissions. I now get a *403 Forbidden* error when trying to log in.

I added my username to the `www-data` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data admin
```

Used the following commands to set the permissions:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod -R 775 {} \
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \
sudo chown admin:www-data -R wp-content/* 
sudo chmod 660 wp-config.php .htaccess
```

Can anyone help as I'm struggling to figure out why as it's actually what WordPress said to do.

Here are the permissions - I think the `sr` is causing the issue on the directories:

```
drwxrwsr-x  9 admin admin  4096 Jun 19 09:57 wp-admin
-rwxrwxr-x  1 admin admin   364 Jun 19 09:56 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxrwxr-x  1 admin admin  1477 Sep 15 17:55 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxrwxr-x  1 admin admin  4840 Sep 15 18:57 wp-config.php
drwxrwsr-x  8 admin admin  4096 Jun 19 10:25 wp-content
```

Comment: Is your hosting managed? Hosting support would be in best position to tell about how it should be on _their_ servers.

Comment: No it's not managed its a shared box

Comment: Seems like you added everything to the `admin` group, while you want the `www-data` group and their permissions on those files…

Answer (score 1):

I removed the sticky permission with using the - instead of the + and the website works.

sudo chmod -R g-s